# Check if 2D LinkedHashSet contains a specific string

Tags: java, linkedhashset

I am trying to find whether a specific string value is found within a 2D LinkedHashSet I have created.

Here is some code for the initialization of the LinkedHashSet:

```
LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>> block = new LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>>();
```

I have tried using .contains like this but it seems to be an incorrect argument type:

```
  int N = Integer.parseInt(b1.readLine());
            for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
                String sorts [] = (b1.readLine()).split(" ");
                if(block.stream().anyMatch(list->list.contains(sorts[0]))) {
                    //System.out.println("I entered");
                    for (Set<String> innerSet : block) {
                        for (String string : innerSet) {
                            if(string.equals(sorts[0])) {
                                innerSet.add(sorts[5]);
                            }
                            if(string.equals(sorts[5])) {
                                innerSet.add(sorts[0]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    block.add(new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(sorts[0], sorts[5]))); 
                }
```

Comment: What's the type of sorts?

Comment: That is the second question of that kind you ask today. Can you share you full attempt? And please create a [MRE].

Comment: @hd1 it is a String.

Comment: @Turing85 my full attempt would not necessarily add any more details to the question since I am only having trouble with this line.

Comment: This question I am solving is from the usaco site. The competition this question is a part of has ended therefore discussion regarding the question is permitted. Here is a link to the question: http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=965 Input is specified on the question page.

Comment: What exception are you getting? Is it a compile-time issue or a run-time issue?

Comment: @MattBerteaux It is a compiler time issue. The exact issue is: Local variable sorts defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Comment: @MattBerteaux Sorts is an array of strings. You can refer to the code I added above for more details.

Comment: Why are you creating a hash set of mutable objects? This sounds like very poor design.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am quite new to algorithms questions. I want to create a block structure that holds the cows that are given constraints. I then want to iterate around these blocks and see if cows can be placed between these blocks, but not within a block. Essentially, I am just trying to represent the cows with constraints as blocks.

Comment: @LavaMaster. Sure. But what piece of knowledge about that particular data structure made you choose it over something more sensible?

Comment: @MadPhysicist At first, I was looking to use a 2D Array or a 2D ArrayList to do this. However, the number of columns changes, so I felt like a 2D Array wouldn't work. Furthermore, I wasn't sure how to implement a 2D ArrayList for something like this. With a 2D LinkedHashSet, I thought that I could represented the blocks in an ordered manner. Also, I thought that it would be easy to utilize .contains (I understand that this method can be used on ArrayLists as well) and edit each HashSet. Is there a better approach to this (I am sure there is)?

Comment: You can create a 2D structure with different inner and outer types. Sets are not good for much besides testing containment. Use a master set in parallel if you want to test for containment.

Comment: What 2D Structure would you recommend for this? Also, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Having looked at the problem, there is definitely no need to use sets here. If you make a list containing a chain of cows, you only ever need to check the first and last elements: a possible ordering is guaranteed by the problem

Comment: Yeah. In terms of the problem, I was able to create an algorithm that places the cows based on the constraints (alphabetically). However, I am unable to figure out an algorithm to use to place the cows that don't have constraints alphabetically. For example, in the question, Belinda, Bessie, and Betsy don't have to be placed in specific positions, but they have to be placed alphabetically in between the blocks of cows that have constraints.

Comment: Just read your edit. What do you mean by "a possible ordering is guaranteed by the problem"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parallelSteam` to make the process concurrent and fast -

```
block.parallelStream()
     .filter(stringSet -> 
          stringSet.contains(input))
     .collect(Collectors.toList()).size() >  0
```

The code above takes `block` (`LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>>`) and the `input` string. Uses multiple **thread** from **fork join pool** to find input string in different sets. Finally it collects all such sets **which contains input** string and checks the size if it's **more than 0** and return true if that is the case, false otherwise.

### EDIT 1

`better version` is this -

```
block.parallelStream().anyMatch(strings -> strings.contains(input))
```

this is much **more efficient** because it will only wait for **first match** and immediately returns true.

`anyMatch` javadoc -

> ```
>  * Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided
>  * predicate.  May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not
>  * necessary for determining the result.  If the stream is empty then
>  * {@code false} is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.
> ```

Comment: You may want to do some testing. The `parallelStream` option is extremely slow unless there is sufficient data to warrant its use.  There is an initial penalty for setting up the threads, etc.

Comment: ForkJoinPool common pool is **statically instantiated** at the time of **ForkJoinPool** class loading. So penalty of thread creation is **one time** which you cant avoid for any thread creation. It will be reused after that which happens to be normal use case in most of the application. And yes you are right its the general issue of concurrency with parallelism, you might end up with more time if there is not much to process.

Comment: @WJS I saw your test code. You can try **multiple run** in **one execution** with parallel stream, you should see **better performance in later runs**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stream.

Populate your hashSet.

```java
      Set<Set<String>> nestedSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

      LinkedHashSet<String> set1 =
            new LinkedHashSet<>(Set.of("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon"));
      LinkedHashSet<String> set2 =
            new LinkedHashSet<>(Set.of("apples", "oranges", "pears", "grapes", "bananas"));

      nestedSet.add(set2);
      nestedSet.add(set1);
```

Test Data

```
      Map<String, Boolean> testData = Map.of("alpha", true, "pears", true, 
      "papayas", false, "eta", false, "omega", false, "house", false);
```

Run it

```
      testData.forEach((item, expectedResult)-> {
         System.out.printf("Item = \"%s\", Expected return = %b, actual = %b%n",
               item,expectedResult, exists(nestedSet, item));
      });
```

```
  public static boolean exists(Set<Set<String>> sets,
         String target) {
      return sets.stream().anyMatch(set->set.contains(target));
  }
```